# NHibernate GetNamedQuery executes stored procedure but returns empty list

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a Stored Procedure that returns 2 records when tested in SQL Studio Management Express using this script:

```
declare @route_id_param as varchar(10), @start_time as datetime, @start_date as datetime, @end_date as datetime
set @start_time = GETDATE()
set @start_date = CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/26/2013',101) 
set @end_date = CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/26/2020',101)     

exec dbo.sp_get_deactivation_list @companyId=1, @startDate = @start_date, @endDate = @end_date;
select execution_time_in_ms = DATEDIFF(millisecond, @start_time, getdate())
GO
```

When I attempt to executed same stored procedure from NHibernate, using the following mapping file, I get 0 results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping 
  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
  assembly="HGT.IridiumAirtime.Service" 
  namespace="HGT.IridiumAirtime.Service.Model">
  <sql-query name="GetDeactivationList" callable="true">
    <query-param name="companyId" type="int"/>
    <query-param name="startDate" type="DateTime"/>
    <query-param name="endDate" type="DateTime"/>
    <!--<return class="Activation">
      <return-property column="MobileId" name="MobileId" />
      <return-property column="RadioAddress" name="RadioAddress" />
      <return-property column="DeactivationDate" name="DeactivationDate" />
    </return>-->
    exec [sp_get_deactivation_list] @companyId=:companyId, @startDate=:startDate, @endDate=:endDate
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The method that executed said Stored Procedure is:

```
   public IEnumerable<TOut> ExecuteStoredProcedure<TOut>(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        IEnumerable<TOut> result;

        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var query = session.GetNamedQuery(procedureName);
            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                query.SetParameter(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value);
            }
            AddStoredProcedureParameters(query, parameters);
            result = query.List<TOut>(); 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I even created a new mapping file for this Activation type even though there is no associated table but NHibernate does not return the correct result. Un-commenting the type mapping definition within the procedure's mapping file does not change outcome. Am I missing something here?

I get no exceptions, so it looks like procedure is being executed.

**UPDATE: 1**  Removed call to **AddStoredProcedureParameters** and replaced with method body.

**UPDATE 2**  Adding Stored Procedure:

```
if OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.[sp_get_deactivation_list]', 'P' ) is not null 
    drop procedure dbo.[sp_get_deactivation_list];
go

create procedure [dbo].[sp_get_deactivation_list]   
    @companyId int,
    @startDate DateTime,
    @endDate DateTime
as
begin       
    select 
        assMobileRadio.Mobile_ID as MobileId, 
        tblRadioinfo.Radio_Address as RadioAddress, 
        tblRadioinfo.Deactivation_Date as DeactivationDate
    from tblRadioinfo 
    left join assMobileRadio 
    on tblRadioinfo.Radio_ID = assMobileRadio.Radio_ID
    where tblRadioinfo.Radio_Type_ID in (2, 4, 7) 
    and tblRadioinfo.Company_ID = @companyId
    and tblRadioinfo.Deactivation_Date <= @endDate
    and tblRadioinfo.Deactivation_Date >= @startDate
    and tblRadioinfo.Radio_Address in (select IMEI from [airtime_cdrs] where  Effective_Date > @startDate and Effective_Date < @endDate)
from airtimes_cte for xml path('')),1,1,''))    
    ORDER BY tblRadioinfo.Deactivation_Date
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried your mapping *(the same as possible)* and your 1) mapping and 2) call is OK. Except the fact that I am not sure about the call inside of the **`AddStoredProcedureParameters`**

So, this is working:

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetDeactivationList");
    query.SetParameter("companyId", 1);
    query.SetParameter("startDate", new DateTime(2013,10,26));
    query.SetParameter("endDate", new DateTime(2020,12,26));

// if the <return class="Activation"> is commented ... we'll get object[]
var list = query.List<object[]>();
```

And this is working. Other words. Your mapping is working. The SQL call (exec sp) is fired, because if the named query won't be find, or some other issues would happen, we will get an `Exception`.

The only suspected right now is the **black box** `AddStoredProcedureParameters` *(could not it switch start and end date?)*

I would suggest, do check your Unit test in the SQL Server Profiler, you will see what is passed to DB... and you can take and reexecute.

Comment: +1 for reference to SQL Profiler.  Since, I am on Express, I used ExpressProfiler from https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/, which confirms the following is being executed:  exec sp_executesql N'exec [sp_get_deactivation_list] @companyId=@p0, @startDate=@p1, @endDate=@p2',N'@p0 int,@p1 datetime,@p2 datetime',@p0=1,@p1='2013-10-26 00:00:00',@p2='2020-12-16 00:00:00'
go.  Still no output.   Why are you doing query.List<object[]> instead of query.List<object>?

Comment: I have a similar stored procedure, called GetTransmissionSum executing successfully through NHibernate. When this one is executed, Express Profiler gives a CPU of 31, Reads of 3788 and Duration of 41ms.  However, when GetDeactivationList is executed, CPU is 0, Reads is 3 and Duration is 0ms.  When I execute test script against GetDeactivationList in Studio Management Express, CPU is 125, Reads 3991 and Duration 124ms.

Comment: When I rexecute query that is being passed to DB, it returns count of 0. Hmmm.

Comment: Feel like a bonehead here.  Query was being executing but there were no results that met the input parameters.  When tested in SME,  used an end time of 12/26/2020 but from my unit test, used 12/16/2020.

Comment: To answer the first question: why `object[]` - because than I know that I am working with an object array of *columns* for each *row*. The results of your measurements are really weird ;( because now we know, that the correct SQL statement is fired... with correct params... but why it is not giving any results?

Comment: Coool, it seems that now we got it, right? the *date* value? that would be the most suspected... wish that you make it ;). This is the real pain, find these little hidden ... bugs... But good that all your NHibernate stuff was done properly!!! ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am getting results but exception is not being throw when NHibernate attempts to map the results to Activation class.  I have <return class="Activation"> uncommented out in the stored proc mapping file.

Comment: Sorry, what are you saying? that the Activation is not filled? what kind of exception is there? Or you mean: no exception - no data? I tested that (very close to your settings) and it was OK... so be patient. You are almost there...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44966/discussion-between-klaus-nji-and-radim-kohler)

Comment: my employer denies access to chat.  But yes, exception is thrown when using var list = query.List<object[]>() with Activation mapping commented or query.List<Activation>() with Activation mapping uncommented.

Comment: I am sorry, I was off. Sorry, I confused you. So! It is this way: 1) you've said, that you removed the `<return class="Activation"` mapping, then we need to use `IList<Object[]>` 2) If we use that mapping again, you are right then we will recieve this. `IList<Activation>()` ... sorry for confusing, but I was following your steps in the question ;) Summary: With the `<return class` I succesfully recived the `Activation`... without that mapping I was able to work with `object[]`

Comment: WIth <return class, do I also need a separate mapping for the Activation class?  If not I get NHibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: {GetDeactivationList}.

Comment: Just found out that I need separate mapping for Activation class and it must contain an Id field.  So needed to add Id field to my return type in the stored procedure mapping;   <return-property column="Id" name="Id" /> and change my stored procedure to return some Id,  assMobileRadio.ID as Id.  Now it all works with  query.List<Activation>().

Comment: Great job. I do admire that you do not gave up! Enjoy NHibernate. It is amazing tool ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I created a blog post on this here: http://klausnji.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

If executing the stored procedure you have is your main purpose (not exactly using GetNamedQuery), you can use the following:

Assuming that your methods' arguments are: int? id, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate (all nullable values)

```
IList<TOut> result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec [dbo].[sp_get_deactivation_list]:param1, :param2, :param3")
    .SetParameter("param1", id, NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .SetParameter("param2", fromDate, NHibernateUtil.DateTime)
    .SetParameter("param3", toDate, NHibernateUtil.DateTime)
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<TOut>()).List<TOut>();

return result;
```

And in your mapping file for class TOut, just have the related properties as normal.

Comment: Thanks but there were other issues which were not related to the call to GetNamedQuery and its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If Activation is non-managed entity with nhibernate you can use this:

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery(procedureName);

AddStoredProcedureParameters(query, parameters);

result = query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(TOut)))
    .List<TOut>();
```

If does try to add `alias`:

```
<return alias="activation" class="Activation">
     ...
</return>
```

For example:

```
<sql-query name="mySqlQuery">
    <return alias="person" class="eg.Person">
        <return-property name="Name" column="myName"/>
        <return-property name="Age" column="myAge"/>
        <return-property name="Sex" column="mySex"/>
    </return>
    SELECT person.NAME AS myName,
           person.AGE AS myAge,
           person.SEX AS mySex,
    FROM PERSON person WHERE person.NAME LIKE :name
</sql-query>
```

Reference [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/querysql.html) are some more ways to solve your issue.
Just you need how to say to nhibernate how return the data, "this" column "resolve this" property.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  query.SetResultTransformer().List<Tout>() is the code I had before running into a related post.  Will try again but I recall, that did not work.  Could you please clarify the second paragraph?  Should I uncomment out the Activation mapping and add an alias?